# No 404 not found template rendered for slugs Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I setup a not found template and it only works for routes which don't have slugs in the URL. Furthermore, the [iron-router-progress](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/iron-router-progress) bar hangs at approx. 95% (same as for the forbidden template). I think it's because the client is waiting for subscription, but there is no returning data.
Here is my code:

```
var admin = function(pause) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        var member = Member.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        if (member) {
            if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), [member.slug], ['admin'])) {
                this.render('forbidden');
                pause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

…

```
this.route('teamMembers', {
        path: '/member/:slug/overview',
        onBeforeAction: admin,
        waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('members', this.params.slug)]; },
        data: function() {
            return Members.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        }
});
```

For insance:

- `/member/john/overview123` -> notFound template rendered (✓)
- `/member123/john/overview` -> notFound template rendered (✓)
- `/member/lisa/overview` (lisa does not exist) -> no notFound template rendered (x)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Do you check the condition if (member)?

Comment: Yes. I think it's because the client waits for the subscription, but the function returns nothing. What do you think?

Comment: one question, do you try to subscribe a the collection members before the method findOne?

Comment: I don't think so. Subscription logic is in waitOn function.

Comment: yes, I know that... only you try maybe the methods are unsynchronized