# Display 404 not found template for 'slugs' when publication returns empty cursor - Meteor - iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

My question is related to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794382/no-404-not-found-template-rendered-for-slugs-meteor), because I have the same issues. If I have a route like this:

```
this.route('userPage', {
    path: '/user/:username',
    waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('userPage', this.params.username)];
    },
    data: function() {
        return Users.findOne({username: this.params.username});
    }
});
```

and my subscription looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('userPage', function(username) {
    return Users.find({username: username}, {fields: {'profile': 1, 'username': 1}});
});
```

The 404 page will be rendered (this is fine), but the [progress-bar](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/iron-router-progress) hangs at 98% or so (why?).
If I have a route like this:

```
this.route('chat', {
        path: '/chat/:slug',
        waitOn: function() { return [ Meteor.subscribe('chat', this.params.slug), Meteor.subscribe('chatAvatars', this.params.slug) ]; },
        data: function() { return Chat.findOne({slug: this.params.slug}); }
    });
```

and my subscriptions like this:

```
Meteor.publish('chat', function(slug) {
    return Chat.find({slug: slug});
});

Meteor.publish('chatAvatars', function(slug) {
    var chat = Chat.findOne({slug: slug});
    if (chat) {
        return Users.find({_id: {$in: chat.participants}}, {fields: {'profile.image': 1, 'username': 1}});
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

No 404 not found template will be rendered. Why? Do I have to check in my `onBeforeAction` if the chat exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to set the publish as ready

```
Meteor.publish('chatAvatars', function(slug) {
var chat = Chat.findOne({slug: slug});
if (chat) {
    return Users.find({_id: {$in: chat.participants}}, {fields: {'profile.image': 1, 'username': 1}});
} else {
     this.ready();//<============here
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now the 404 not found template is rendered, but can you tell me why the progress bar never finishes?

Comment: Somehow one of your subscriptions is never ready. Are you sure you have no errors on server side? Or could you give a small github repo where I can check what you do?

Comment: I cannot provide a github repo at the moment, but thank you for your help! Do you know how I can 'debug' this? The `progressDebug` mode is not really helpful :/

Comment: Maybe checking your DDP logs with ddp-analyser-proxy or trying to subscribe without iron-router and see if it is IRP which fails to finish the loading or your subscriptions.